# GET HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error when trying to access view using the
following url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hello-view/. I have posted
code below incorporated `views.py` and `urls.py` created in my django-app. I will appreciate if review codes and advise where the errors are:

Error message:

```
HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept
 
{
    "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed."
}
```

`views.py`:

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class HelloApiView(APIView):
    
    def get(self,request, format=None):
        """Returns a list of APIView features"""

        an_apiview = [
            'Uses HTTP methods as functions (get, post, patch, put, delete)',
            'Is similar to a traditional Django View',
            'Gives you the most control over your logic',
            'Is mapped manually to URLs',
        ]

        return Response({'message': 'Hello!', 'an_apiview': an_apiview})
```

`urls.py`:

```
from django.urls import path

from profiles_api import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('hello-view/', views.HelloApiView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Use something like Postman https://www.postman.com/downloads/ to make a post request.When you visit a URL you make a GET request which are generally not used in API but rather a POST request which can be made using Async Request or some API Client.

Comment: @DushyantDeshwal not familiar with postman - any further advise how it can help?. thanks

Comment: You can make the api available on GET request by using decorator `api_view` https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view . 

You see here in installation you can also `pip install markdown` so that it will allow you to browse your api https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#installation.

Comment: Dushyant Deshwal let me try

Comment: Dushyant Deshwal I used both @api_view and markdown it is not working. Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: I usually work with function based views and here you are using class based maybe i cannot help any further because i am not that familiar with this.https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/ Refer to documentation and try to make a similar function using your Models. I think this should be enough to follow.Documentation is good for Restframework.

Comment: thanks I found what was a problem. there was some indentation issue in the code